# "Enlarging" a 2D array by factor (m,n)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

Say I have a 2D array of size h1 x w1

I want to enlarge it (Just like we enlarge an image) by a factor m,n

So that my resulting array if of the size h1*m , w1*n

for example, I have an array arr1[2][2] of size (2, 2)
01
 11
 
Now I enlarged it by a factor (3, 3) so my new array arr2[6][6] becomes
000111
000111
000111
111111
111111
111111

Can you suggest me an algorithm / iterative loop which could generate arr2 by given information ?

Comment: "I want to enlarge it" --> Arrays in C, once defined, cannot have their size change. Consider instead allocating memory for the data and use pointers.

Comment: Choose C or C++

Comment: That's not too difficult for you to try solving yourself. Think about how you'd do this for 1x1 -> 1x2, then think how you'd do it to 1x1 -> 2x2, then 2x2 -> 4x4 and then for variable input. Good luck!

Comment: Amit, can you please provide an iterative relation? I have tried a lot, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: You will have a better response if you take a shot at solving this yourself and asking questions based on your solution if necessary. If your attempt works, but you think it can be improved, consider asking at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Note I've linked to the Asking section of the help pages. I strongly recommend a read-through before posting there. Good idea to read [ask] here at Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: @GargYashit In the question you say you want to enlarge (i.e. change size) of a 2D matrix. In a comment you say you want to make a new matrix with different size. That's two different things. Please edit your question to make clear what you want to do. The best is if you can add some code to illustrate it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I use pointers to arrays in a smart way to index continuous memory as 2d array and a declarator for VLA in a function prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
#define ERR_ON(expr, msg, ...) \
    do{ if(expr) { fprintf(stderr, "%d: error %s failed: " msg "\n", __LINE__, #expr, ##__VA_ARGS__); exit(-1); } }while(0)

/**
 * Input: array p with x columns and y rows
 * Output: int arr[y * factory][x * factorx]
 *          newly allocated array created from p resized by a factorx and factory
 */
void *arr2d_getenlarged(size_t x, size_t y, int p[y][x], size_t factorx, size_t factory)
{
    const size_t newx = x * factorx;
    const size_t newy = y * factory;

    int (* const ret)[newx] = malloc(sizeof(*p) * newx * newy);
    ERR_ON(ret == NULL, "");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            const int val = p[i][j];
            for (size_t m = 0; m < factorx; ++m) {
                for (size_t n = 0; n < factory; ++n) {
                    ret[i * factorx + m][j * factory + n] = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

void arr2d_print(size_t x, size_t y, int (*arr)[x])
{
    printf("--- %p ---\n", (void*)arr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            printf("[%d,%d]=%d   ", i, j, arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int (*arr)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 2);
    ERR_ON(arr == NULL, "");
    memcpy(arr, (int[2][2]){{0,1},{1,1}}, sizeof((int[2][2]){0}));

    arr2d_print(2, 2, arr);

    int (*arr3)[6] = (void*)arr2d_getenlarged(2, 2, &arr[0][0], 3, 3);

    arr2d_print(6, 6, arr3);

    free(arr);
    free(arr3);

    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
--- 0x1203010 ---                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[0,0]=0   [0,1]=1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[1,0]=1   [1,1]=1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--- 0x1203030 ---                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[0,0]=0   [0,1]=0   [0,2]=0   [0,3]=1   [0,4]=1   [0,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
[1,0]=0   [1,1]=0   [1,2]=0   [1,3]=1   [1,4]=1   [1,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
[2,0]=0   [2,1]=0   [2,2]=0   [2,3]=1   [2,4]=1   [2,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
[3,0]=1   [3,1]=1   [3,2]=1   [3,3]=1   [3,4]=1   [3,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
[4,0]=1   [4,1]=1   [4,2]=1   [4,3]=1   [4,4]=1   [4,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
[5,0]=1   [5,1]=1   [5,2]=1   [5,3]=1   [5,4]=1   [5,5]=1                                                                                                                                                                   
Hello World
```

Live version available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/r1EcV7quQ).

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ENLARGEX 3
int src[2][2] = {{0,1},{1,1}};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    int **dest;
    //int dest[6][6] ={0,};
    int i, j;
    int sizesrc = sizeof(src)/sizeof(int)/2;

    dest = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*sizesrc*ENLARGEX);
    for (i = 0; i < sizesrc*ENLARGEX; i++) {
        dest[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*sizesrc*ENLARGEX);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizesrc*ENLARGEX; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < sizesrc*ENLARGEX; j++) {
            dest[i][j] = src[i/ENLARGEX][j/ENLARGEX];
            printf("%d ", dest[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizesrc*ENLARGEX; i++) {
        free(dest[i]);
    }
    free(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (int)` is not necessarily the same as `sizeof (int*)`; i.e. you have a bug in the first `malloc()` call. Also you didn't `free()` the resources and forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`.